# Left join with on a limited right table

Tags: sql

I have cards, schedules, users. Each schedule has foreign keys to a user and a card. Assuming I have 100 cards and 2 users, each with 10 schedules. I would like a set of 100 cards joined with the 10 schedules of only 1 of the users. When I try to limit my dataset to 1 of the users, I only end up with 10 rows. How can I set up a query to achieve what I want?

Comment: can you share your table scripts? It will be useful to test a possible answer before posting it here

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: If you do `OUTER JOIN` first and then `INNER JOIN`, then 2nd `JOIN` can filter out the `NULL`s created by a first `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want something in the form of:

```
select *
from cards c
left join 
(
  select *
  from schedules s
  join users u on s.UserID = u.ID
  where u.ID = 1
) x on c.ID = x.CardID
```

So that your where clause doesn't interfere with the left join. You'll have to change the column names to whatever you are using, and possibly explicitly list the columns in the sub-query so there isn't any issues with overlapping column names.

Comment: Thank you! This does what I need. How is it in terms of efficiency?

Comment: It's a pretty basic query.  You're just telling the database to perform the inner join before the outer join.  However, no outer join is considered to be super efficient, but sometimes that's the data your after.  With relatively small datasets and ensuring you're joining on indexed columns, which from your note about foreign keys I assume you are, then I doubt you'll notice any performance impact.